# javascript how to avoid numbered object keys to be sorted automatically

Tags: javascript, object

I have this:

```js
const obj = {};
obj['7'] = {name: '7'};
obj['5'] = {name: '5'};
obj['3'] = {name: '3'};

console.log(obj);
```

The expected output is:

```
{ 
   '7' : { name: '7'}, 
   '5' : { name: '5'}, 
   '3' : { name: '3'}
}
```

But instead, I got:

```
{ 
   '3' : { name: '3'}, 
   '5' : { name: '5'}, 
   '7' : { name: '7'}
}
```

How can I overcome this?

Comment: You cannot. The specs define the ordering of positive integer keys to be in ascending order. You should instead be using a different way to keep the order, if it's important.

Comment: @VLAZ, yes, the order is important. thanks for the tip...

Comment: Use a `Map` instead. Maps preserve insertion order. Objects don't.

Comment: @VLAZ can you provide some clear example?

Comment: why not take an array?

Comment: @alex clear example of the spec or a data structure?

Comment: @NinaScholz, it has to be an object... I wish it would be an array

Comment: You can likely use an array or, if you need an object,  provide a change to symbol.iterator to return the values in a specific order

Comment: An array *is* an object.

Comment: @trincot everything is an object. I think the understanding is that we're all referring to the object type.

Comment: @zfrisch, *"everything is an object"*: no. *"referring to the object type"*: `typeof [] === "object"`

Comment: Related: [Does ES6 introduce a well-defined order of enumeration for object properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30076219)

Comment: ... what? What are you arguing for. Saying that an Array is an object doesn't really pertain to what the user was saying in context.